# User has negative score on a question and gets +5 in his stats?

Tags: support, reputation

I just came across this user's profile, [krypton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3438431/krypton), and noticed something odd. He has negative score on a question and gets +5 in his stats. Is this normal behavior of Stack Overflow or did something out of norm occur here?

Comment: The last vote in that question with negative score was an upvote. The downvotes before did not reduce the rep of that user because you can't have negative rep.

Comment: The order of votes is important.  Since score cannot be negative, it matters when any upvotes occured.  For example, if someone with 1 rep gets 100,000 downvotes, then 1 update, there rep would be still be +6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Users must have a positive reputation.  Downvotes on a user with 1 reputation remove no reputation, as they have none that they can lose.  When an upvote was made on the post after all of the downvotes, the normal +5 was applied.