# Dupe titles are escaped in app

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions, ios-app

First off, kudos on implementing closed questions in the app. A lot to cover I'm sure.

The banner reads:

> This post already has an answer here:
>   How does &quot;Reputation&quot; work?

On this post: [User has negative score on a question and gets +5 in his stats?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226172/user-has-negative-score-on-a-question-and-gets-5-in-his-stats)

> [image]

The title is fine in the question view itself:

> [image]

Also, the title doesn't say **[duplicate]**.

Comment: Thanks for the bug report, I'm taking a look at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops, missed decoding some HTML entities here.

This should be fixed in **version 0.1.27**.